Nuance of nan desu no/なんですの here in this context
I'm having trouble with nan desu no/なんですの , not sure what did it mean exactly (could only guess "What's going on here" based on context). Hope someone could tell me its correct nuance here !
Context: A palace guard general/袁紹 had been forced to retreat from the palace of a capital, which is where she supposed to protect the Emperor/空丹さま. But her other 3 subordinates had suggested that since their force has been mostly eliminated, they should retreat now to have a comeback chance later.
文醜「……斗詩ィッ！乗れ！」
顔良「うん！真直ちゃん、捕まって！！」
田豊「……あ、ありがと、斗詩！」
文醜「麗羽さまも逃げますよ！」
袁紹「猪々子さん！禁城にはまだ天子様が！！」
文醜「あんな化け物、あたいらだけじゃどうしようもないですって！いったん退いて、体勢を整えましょう！」
顔良「そうですよ！冀州に戻れば、再起の目はあります！それに天子様は、趙忠殿たちが何とかしてくれてますよ！！」
袁紹「…………ぐっ！！」
袁紹「な……なんですの。どうしてわたくしたちが、空丹さまが、こんな理不尽な目に遭わなければなりませんの……」
袁紹「おのれ董卓……おのれ董仲穎！！」
「この恨み、絶対に……絶対に許しませんわよ！覚えてらっしゃい！」

This なんですの just means "What's going on?" or "What's all this about?", but said in the stereotypical ojōsama language. You might think of it as a questioning version of ですわ. An equivalent in everyday speech would be なんなの, なんなんだ or なんなんですか. Are you reading some scenario where Yuan Shao is depicted as a noble lady?

yes, even in real life this character is also a noble , i think the author used history as reference to write story

@MemoriesPlastic I'm not sure what you mean by "real life"... Looks like you're reading one of those 武将女体化 games, but if you don't mind, could you share the name of the work so we can have more context in the future?

the game is sangokuhime 4
